# Python API using Github questions for beginner

Tags: python-2.7, cmd, github-api, appannie

I learned the basics of python and now i want to use the API package of Appannie From Github.
Link: https://github.com/Ossus/appannie

In the readme written

**Simply open settings.py and add your API key, then run the script:
$ ./appannie.py**

Where I run the  $ ./appannie.py**?
If you could add an explanation when to use the cmd?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `appannie.py` is a directly runnable script. You can clone the repository to your local machine, and run it:

```
python appannie.py
```

In the same directory is a `settings.py` file in which you need to put your API key (on line 8). This is AppAnnie's API, though—not GitHub's API, so you'll need an API key from them.

Comment: when I want to use some module from the appannie.py what should I do in order to use some built in functions there like                                                                
def _reviews(account, app_id, start=None, end=None): should i import and move the file to specific file in order to use this function?

Comment: If you'd like to use the script in your own application, it _should_ be enough to copy the file into your project, `import appannie` and access the functions  as `appannie._reviews(...)` and so on.